# caption on img push the text around img down

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to put a caption on img by img class "imageHolader" & "caption" and keep the text align (to the right side) to the img. The problem is, that this caption (classes) push the text under the img. I tried to solve this in different ways, but don't succesful, to me it seems like a problem with position property. Thank You for advice.

```
<section>
<div class="container-fluid bg_color cont-padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <a name="myanchor"></a>
             <div class="imageHolder">
             <img src="img/a1.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="imgsectionleft" alt="moscow subway typical train">
             <div class="caption"><br>Metro w Moskwie
             </div>
             </div>
             <h3><i class="fa fa-star fa-1x"></i> How did it all start</h3>
                <p class="section-text text-justify">London has the world’s oldest underground rail system; Tokyo’s metro has employees to push people into packed trains; New York’s subway is an ethnic melting pot. Hidden beneath the streets of Moscow is something completely different. To step onto the Moscow metro is to step back in time and immerse yourself in a museum rich in architecture and history.</p>

CSS:

.imageHolder { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 320px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: left; 
} 
.imageHolder .caption { 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 70px; 
    bottom: -9px; 
    left: 0px; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    background: 
    #000000; 
    text-align:center; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    opacity:0.5; 
}
#imgsectionleft {
    float:left;
    width:240px;
    height:320px;
    margin-right:2%; 
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    border: 11px solid #0D1447;
> Blockquote
```

Comment: I don't understand. do you want the text to the right and at the bottom or to the right and top?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/jrzgwyup/

Comment: I want text to the right and bottom, next to the img with caption. When i doing like above, the text start to go under the img like here: https://jsfiddle.net/4wx1d1tp/